# torchmetrics BinaryMatthewsCorrCoef outputs 0 if target and prediction contains only one case either positive or negative case

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, model-evaluations, metric

I stared using MCC(Matthew's correlation coefficient) metric. But getting unexpected values when the given target and pred contains only one case either positive or negative (case  - 1), The output of BinaryMatthewsCorrCoef is always 0. But we can clearly say that predictions are same as the targets. And for the case - 2, If the preds and targets are completely different, the MCC is also zero. Is this expected behaviour with MCC or some other issue.

```py
mcc = BinaryMatthewsCorrCoef()

# preds and targets are equal (case - 1)
print(mcc(torch.ones(10), torch.ones(10)))
print(mcc(torch.zeros(10), torch.zeros(10)))

# preds and targets are completely different (case - 2)
print(mcc(torch.ones(10), torch.zeros(10)))
```

```py
tensor(0)
tensor(0)
tensor(0)
```

In this [blog](https://bmcgenomics.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s12864-019-6413-7), They are handling these cases slightly different. Below are the MCC values using their [implementation](https://gist.github.com/lokesh1199/3d899b03e37107565cd91d6ad6d8db90). These values represent model performance more accurately than the torchmetrics version.

case - 1 -> MCC = 1.0
case - 2 -> MCC = -1.0

Kindly tell if this should be handled differently?